# Passing ViewModel to a View not clearing down?

Tags: asp.net-core, view, binding

I have a project wrote in ASP.Net Core 3.1. I have a view model which has a list of all my surveyors and a single model of a surveyor. The list is used in my table to show all entries and the single model is used to bind to input controls in my Razor View. On submit I all an update method in my controller and check if the id of the passed model is 0 or not. If 0 I add it to my database and if not I update that entry. This all works fine. I then return to the view with a new viewmodel. My problem is it is not clearing the single entry so all the input controls still have the previously added entry.

View:

```html
@model SurveyorViewModel

<link href="~/CSS/Surveyor.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="SurveyorList" asp-controller="Surveyor" asp-action="update" method="post" class="mt-3">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Surveyor.PK_Id" />
    <div id="cover" class="container vertical-center col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 mx-auto form p-4" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);">
        <div id="divSurveyorList" class="table mt-2">
            <table id="surveyorList" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size: 12px; width: 150px;">Surveyors</span>
                        </th>
                        <th style="font-size: 12px; width: 40px; color:#6d6d6d;">Edit/Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var surveyor in Model.SurveyorList)
                        {
                            <tr style="color: #6d6d6d; font-family: Verdana; font-size:12px; font-weight:100;">
                                <td>
                                    @surveyor.FullName
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Surveyor" asp-action="EditSurveyor" asp-route-Id=@surveyor.PK_Id><span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span></a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-controller="Surveyor" asp-action="DeleteSurveyor" asp-route-Id=@surveyor.PK_Id )><span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start mt-1">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label asp-for="Surveyor.FullName" class="col-sm-2 col-md-12 nopadding col-form-label">Full Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input asp-for="Surveyor.FullName" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <label asp-for="Surveyor.Address_Line_1" class="col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-form-label">Address</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <input asp-for="Surveyor.Address_Line_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Line 1" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <input asp-for="Surveyor.Address_Line_2" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Line 2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <input asp-for="Surveyor.Town" class="form-control" placeholder="Town" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <input asp-for="Surveyor.Postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Post Code" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <label asp-for="Surveyor.ContactNo" class="col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-6 col-form-label">Telephone No.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <input asp-for="Surveyor.ContactNo" class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone No." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <label asp-for="Surveyor.Email_Address" class="col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-6 col-form-label">Email Address</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <input asp-for="Surveyor.Email_Address" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2"><span class="fas fa-plus-circle"></span> Update</button>
            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-2" asp-controller="Surveyor" asp-action="Create" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 20px;" )><span class="fas fa-plus-circle"></span><span> Create</span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mr-2" asp-controller="Surveyor" asp-action="Back" style="width: 90px;" )><span class="fas fa-hand-point-left"></span><span> Back</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

ViewModel:

```html
    public class SurveyorViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Surveyor> SurveyorList { get; set; }
        public Surveyor Surveyor { get; set; }
    }
```

Model:

```html
    public class Surveyor
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        public int PK_Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(120)]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Address_Line_1 { get; set; }
        public string Address_Line_2 { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string ContactNo { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email_Address { get; set; }
        public bool Archived { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Methods:

```html
        private SurveyorViewModel PopulateLists()
        {
            SurveyorViewModel SurveyorViewModel = new SurveyorViewModel();
            SurveyorViewModel.SurveyorList = context.Surveyors.ToList();
            SurveyorViewModel.Surveyor = new Surveyor();

            return SurveyorViewModel;
        }

                public IActionResult update(Surveyor surveyor)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (surveyor.PK_Id == 0)
                {
                     surveyor = addSurveyor(surveyor);
                }
                else
                {
                     surveyor = updateSurveyor(surveyor);
                }
            }
            SurveyorViewModel surveyorViewModel = PopulateLists();
            surveyorViewModel.Surveyor = surveyor;

            return View("Surveyor", surveyorViewModel);
        }
```

I've altered my update routine which when doing the add the PK_Id has a value which is passed to the view but when I inspect the elements my hidden field has a value of zero. I did a bit of research and found the following bit of code, when doing the inspect my hidden value has the correct PK_Id value but this is not passed to my controller???

```html
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Surveyor.PK_Id" name="PK_Id" />
```

Many thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution from an old post on here. Basically before I populate a new instance of my viewmodel I use ModelState.Remove("PK_Id"). From what I have read the view will use the default that was past when the post was executed meaning in my case because it was a new entry it would have been 0. By including the remove statement it uses the new Id that I have set in my model.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is it is not clearing the single entry so all the input controls still have the previously added entry.

In the following code,you set `surveyorViewModel.Surveyor` with the previously added entry

```
   SurveyorViewModel surveyorViewModel = PopulateLists();
                surveyorViewModel.Surveyor = surveyor;
    
                return View("Surveyor", surveyorViewModel);
```

You can try to remove `surveyorViewModel.Surveyor = surveyor;`,so that the input controls will not have the previously added entry.

> I've altered my update routine which when doing the add the PK_Id has a value which is passed to the view but when I inspect the elements my hidden field has a value of zero. I did a bit of research and found the following bit of code, when doing the inspect my hidden value has the correct PK_Id value but this is not passed to my controller???

Where you pass the PK_Id to view,and where you have the code `<input type="hidden" value="@Model.Surveyor.PK_Id" name="PK_Id" />`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to remove adding the added surveyor entry so it was an empty model but it still showed the previous entry. As you can see @Model.Surveyor.PK_Id is being populated when I assign the newly added model. I then pass the viewmodel which has this set and a list of the model to populate a table. If I use <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Surveyor.PK_Id" name="PK_Id"/> and inspect that element it has the correct Id but if I use the asp-for helper tag it is always zero (<input type="hidden" asp-for="Surveyor.PK_Id" />).

Comment: I have worked out how to get the hidden value using IFormCollection in the controller but I see this as a hack rather than a fix. Surely the asp-for helper tag should work.